# Difference between old and new state

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am developing a SOAP server that should send state changes to clients. The server communicate with other systems to update its internal state.

I am searching for a solution (pattern o whatever) that let me track the state changes after an update. I watched to [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) but it is not what I am looking for, because I don't need the previous state but the **change**. I can't simply propagate the change to clients because its a pull architecture (clients poll for changes).

**Use case**

Suppose the server state is a `list` of object with 3 elements and the update modifies it adding a new element. The client must receive only the newly added element and **not** a list with 4 elements.

Any solution?

Comment: This might be a better question for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Essentially you're saying, in a system where clients poll for changes, that you want the server to send updates to clients.   That is contradictory.    You probably need to rethink whether the clients are pulling or the server is pushing - what you're seeking would be more consistent with the server pushing information.

Comment: Also if you are creating a web service you should be striving to make it stateless and idempotent. I believe one way to do this is to for example enumerate the updates and attach that number to each update (I don't know if this makes sense in your use case) and have the client request the updates since the last number it received.

Comment: @PaulRooney when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a set of serializable commands (see command design pattern for further details) that are generated whenever a change must be performed.
Then you can execute those commands locally to apply changes to your model and serialize those commands in a queue. Whenever a client pulls them, it can simply reapply the same commands in order to its local model and get the same result you achieved server side.
Somehow your server behaves exactly like a client in regard of the changes to be applied, with the difference that it *pulls* them immediately.

Considering your use case, commands can be defined as insertions in a list and created along with all the required parameters. You can easily extend it to deletions and updates to the objects of the list.

Comment: I think your answer could be correct. Just one more clarification: since I have to keep a list of command for each client, how can I empty the list after each send? Should I also keep a copy of the state updated for each client?

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi If you plan to create a list for each client, clear the list after each read and that's all. The right answer mostly depends on the actual problem, it's hard to say what's the best for you.